# Can't prevent redirect - submit form in modal

Tags: ajax, forms, submit, bootstrap-modal, preventdefault

I have a simple submit form that is inside a bootstrap modal  This code works fine if I don't use a modal, but once inside the modal,  the preventDefault no longer works and the submit function redirects to the page to my endpoint :(   Any ideas what bootstrap's modal is doing to break the preventDefault?  Or another way to prevent the redirect?

```
<div id="bootstrapModal" class="bootstrapModal">
<div id="modal-dialog" class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
<form action="/myendpoint.cmd" id="myForm" name="myForm" role="form">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="email" name="userEmail" class="form-control" id="emailSignUp"   placeholder="Email Address">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="emailbtn"">Sign Up</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div




<script>
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function(data) {
    console.log('success!')
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

may you can try with jquery syntax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function(data) {
        console.log('success!')
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: and make sure form action='#' <form action="#" id="myForm" name="myForm" role="form">

Comment: Hmm... closer.   I no longer was redirected off the page - but, it did refresh the page, which I can't have either...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have invalid (double quoted) written in button that might break the behaviour.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="emailbtn"">Sign Up</button>
```

Just remove the duplicate quotes like below:

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="emailbtn">Sign Up</button>`